# How to automatically insert user name in snowflake external browser authentication

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I try to connect to snowflake via `external browser` authentication. 
My connection string looks like
`jdbc:snowflake://host/?allowMultiQueries=true&db=MY_DB&warehouse=MY_WARE&authenticator=externalbrowser&user=USER&`
 but authorization form always ask me user name ? 
[image]
I don't find the solution for this.
The second question:

How to modify this form and add password on this form too

Answer (score -1):

Just for your information, I do work for Snowflake, to answer your question, why it still asks for the username, you have to use the full username. For example, please see the example that Sriga uses in this community question: [enter link description here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009T38Z5SAJ/when-i-try-to-connect-to-snowflake-using-snowsql-with-using-user-credentials-getting-error-message-related-to-saml-response-is-this-user-privilege-issue)

As for the second question, one option might be to possible to set up another Federated Authentication  or IdP that asks for the user name and password and by changing the "authenticator".

Another option, have you tried not including a username or password in the connection string?